# Where does Google Chrome for Linux store user specific data?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, bookmarks

Where does Google Chrome for Linux store user specific data such as bookmarks ? 
I can't find a `.chrome` or `.google` directory under my home directory, any other directory I should look at ?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I think it stores in `~/.config/google-chrome` or `~/.config/chromium`. Though i have it inside the first location!
Check for the `Default` folder under this location, more specifically.

Comment: Yup - it was at ~/.config/google-chrome/Default. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Programs following the [XDG base directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) store configuration under `./config/PROGRAMNAME/` and data under `.local/share/PROGRAMNAME/`. It looks like Chrome only uses the first directory.

Answer (score 11):

It is usually in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks`, where "Default" is its way of dealing with usernames and different possible sessions. However, it could also be in `~/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks`.

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find at all on internet where the chromium data folder is supposed to be. I found some locations like `~/.config/google-chrome` or `~/.config/chromium` but that wasn't it for me.

I couldn't find this in the settings either... But I found a way:

- On your chrome/chromium go to `chrome://extensions` in the URL bar
- Pick any extension (or the one you're trying to find)
- Then copy the extension id from one of those locations

[image]

- Open a terminal and run `find ~/ -type d -name "id-of-the-extension-here"`

In my case it was in `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Extensions/`

Answer (score 4):

Simply open chrome and type `chrome://version/` in address bar and look for *Profile Path*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There's not a lot to add to this to improve the answer, but if we had too:
Find that *Profile Path* directory to your new home directory and you'll move over all your bookmarks and settings.