# how can I get a direct link to downloads on the app store?

Tags: google-chrome

Because all I have is satellite for broadband and my bandwidth is capped, I'd like to download files from the app store on off-hours.  Rather than staying up until midnight to initiate a transfer, I'd like to schedule a download.  In order to do that, I need the URL of the file from the app store.  Unfortunately, I can't select links and copy them.  Does anyone know how to grab the url for the app install OR when a file is downloading in Chrome, how to grab the download location?

Comment: What device what store? Chrome store? Are you on a desktop? BOY I NEED ANSWERS

Comment: Uh, Chrome on the PC.

Comment: And you can't get the software from some other source?

Comment: Related: [Copy Chrome extensions from one computer to another](http://superuser.com/questions/634648/download-and-install-chrome-extensions-offline).

Comment: @Arjan Not related.... at all.

Comment: Then [your comment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tSHMh.png) is useless too, @Griffin?

Comment: @Arjan Never said it wasn't.

Comment: (As an aside, @Griffin, that question [used to be titled "Download and install Chrome extensions offline"](http://superuser.com/posts/634648/revisions), but it was not answered as such, so I decided to rename that one rather than vote to close this one. I still feel it is related though.)

Comment: @Arjan Actually it can still be relevant. You see if you look at the answer for the link you posted you'll find it's past the download point. They already have it but they just need to copy it to another machine. Mine implies pre-download.

Comment: Arjan's link would be a valid work-around if I could pre-download the file (as Griffin suggested).  And, I would do so, but I don't know where to find the file.  I also considered Wireshark so I could sniff my own traffic.  However, that doesn't work when it's pulling securely.  And, no Griffin, I don't accept "can't" as the answer.  This isn't IE, after all.  It just means the answer is to hack the browser.  According to [Google's documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#type-DownloadItem), there's API access to the downloads.  All I have to do is access them.

Comment: I would, however, like an explanation of the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Nope it doesn't seem to be possible, they hide the download link, however when apps are actually installing into the browser itself it's possible to pause the download. You'd still have to stay up all night (yet I don't see how this can be thwarted without automated installation). So yea. While it's not the answer you want it's the answer.