# How do you copy chrome extension data from one computer to another?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have a new computer with some extensions that block certain websites that I'm likely to procrastinate on.

I have a whole list (because I have no self discipline) that cannot be re-imported, and needs to be entered one site at a time into the extension.

My method was to goto the actual extension folder in app data and just copy all the data over, but this has worked to no avail.

How would one go about saving plenty of time and importing this data?

EDIT: There seems to be another question similar to mine on this matter which copies the data from the extensions folder and the uses developer mode, then load unpacked extension. This installs the extension however the contents of the extension are completely new - no data is copied over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Chrome extensions from one computer to another](https://superuser.com/questions/634648/copy-chrome-extensions-from-one-computer-to-another)

Comment: Trying the method outlined in that question works to install the extension, but unfortunately the data does not cross over with it.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to completely export my extension and their settings by exporting these folders:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Extension Settings
```

Comment: the last folder helped me to transfer the settings (extension installed in both browsers)

Answer (score 1):

You can try copying your entire user profile if there is nothing of concern in the secondary computer.

Just copy the entire profile folder from the primary computer to the secondary. This folder here: `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\UserData\Default`

Usually if you have your Chrome signed in to your google account all of this stuff syncs also. Chrome just backs up your profile and restores it on another system if you have them both signed in.

My preference would be to make sure Chrome was signed in to my Google account. This is a very convenient backup that Google has provided for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was just now able to migrate an extension’s settings by **copying its ID folder in `%AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Extension Settings`**.

`Sync Extension Settings` is the most common place for extensions to save their (options) data, but several others are available, for example `Local Extension Settings` and `IndexedDB`.