# Copy Chrome extension to other account

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-accounts

Is there a way to copy all installed Chrome extensions from one account to another one? Sometime we use multiple accounts and we would like to use the same extensions. Apparently you're required to manually install all extensions on each account... Similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/634648/copy-chrome-extensions-from-one-computer-to-another), but different, as in may case I am referring to multiple accounts, not computers!